# Will my object update the way I think it will update using this method (C#)?

Tags: c#

This might seem like a CS101 question, but I've managed to thoroughly confuse myself.

```
    //this is inside a service class
    ObjectToUpdate objectToUpdate = objectrepository.Get(objectToUpdate.Id);
    SecondObject secondObject = secondObjectRepository.Get(secondObject.Id);
    objectToUpdate.Update(secondObject);
    objectRepository.Save(objectToUpdate);

    //the object itself
    public class ObjectToUpdate {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void Update(SecondObject secondObject) {
    Name = secondObject.Name
    }
}
```

When I get to the "Save" line, it will correctly have updated the objectToUpdate with the name from the secondObject, correct? It carries a reference to itself when you pass it to the Update method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, classes are passed around by reference, so you will be passing a reference to the same object.  This tutorial provides a great reference for understanding this concept: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_memory01122006130034PM/csharp_memory.aspx?ArticleID=9adb0e3c-b3f6-40b5-98b5-413b6d348b91&PagePath=/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_memory01122006130034PM/csharp_memory.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That looks correct to me. When you get to the Save() line, `objectToUpdate.Name` will be the same as `secondObject.Name`

---

If it is easier to read logically, you could change this line to include "this."

```
this.Name = secondObject.Name
```

so that you realize that the Name property being set is the one that belongs to 'this' which is the same object instance that the method was called on. The code is functionally identical, but might be easier to comprehend?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the value of a .NET Object is actually the memory address where that object is stored. Saying `firstObject = secondObject` wouldn't affect the secondObject referenced in the calling method, but saying `firstObject.Name = secondObject.Name` will change the value of the `Name`.